# iOS - Observer to observe tableView dequeue Reusable Cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, observers

Is it possible to add an observer in iOS development for when a cell is dequeued and reused inside a `UITableView`?

Thanks.

Comment: The only way that comes to mind would require you to check the return value of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and post some notification if it's not nil.  (I'm curious what you're trying to accomplish.)

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass UITableViewCell and then override the `[UITableViewCell prepareForReuse]` method. Note that this will only work if your cell subclass has a reuse identifier associated with it so make sure you set a value for that property.

Answer (score 1):

// use to tag your cell with id

```
cell.Tag = item.ID;
```